# FirebaseMessaging.instance.getAPNSToken always return null

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

**Describe the bug**
I have an issue on which i was not able to get APNs token on ios. the push notification works fine on android. I go through [FCM apple integration](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration) steps repeated with no luck. I am stuck on this issue for weeks.

*package versions and testing device*

- flutter: 2.2.3
- firebase_core: 1.8.0
- firebase_messaging: 10.0.9
- iPhone 7: 14.4.1 (real device)

*xcode configuration*

I enable *push notification* and *background mode*(background fetch, remote notification, background process) capabilities in debug and release mode.

AppDelegate.swift
  
  ```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
override func application(
_ application: UIApplication,
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
) -> Bool {
FirebaseApp.configure()
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
}
return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}
}

````
</details>

<details>

  <summary>debug console</summary>
  
  ```flutter: User granted permission
8.8.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM002022] APNS device token not set before retrieving FCM Token for Sender ID '662970956514'. Notifications to this FCM Token will not be delivered over APNS.Be sure to re-retrieve the FCM token once the APNS device token is set.
flutter: APNSToken: null
flutter: Token: c0yzY5QV4EUFudl0fmcCfA:APA91bHzAM9e2jfPEoDBnHQE9xCIG-EwnGatI9RDYPJQ4Apm5tOujBsplHyAqTm2V7DEPXSmDaPcr1okv6qhP-eoWHNmPs3e8IgN9CI4ErS2-W54_EydI2ypZ9ckJNOluLV_ECtWyP4i
[Client] Updating selectors after delegate removal failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 85 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated from this process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 85 named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated from this process.}
````

Output of `flutter doctor -v`
  
  ```Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on macOS 11.6 20G165 darwin-x64, locale
    en-ET)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.61.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!Ï```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did anyone solve above issue in flutter?

Comment: I got same issue, needs help.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using a iOS simulators:
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/notifications

FCM via APNs does not work on iOS Simulators. To receive messages & notifications a real device is required.

Comment: I got same issue because I run my flutter app via simulator, instead run on a real device, the token returns correctly.